# SQL query giving weird result - count

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

This is my SQL query:

```
select 
client_details.client_id, 
count( PC.cheque_status ) as count_stat, 
client_details.client_city, 
client_details.account_created_on, 
client_details.client_name, 
SUM(PC.amount), 
SUM(PNB.amount), 
SUM(PCA.amount), 
PC.cheque_status, 
count(PNB.status), 
count(PCA.status), 
PSD.version 
                      from `client_details` as `client_details` 
                      inner join `products_sold_details` as `PSD` on `PSD`.`client_id` = `client_details`.`client_id` and PSD.version = 1
                      left join product_cheque_mapped PCM on PCM.product_sold_id = PSD.id
                      left join product_cash_mapped PCAM on PCAM.product_sold_id = PSD.id
                      left join product_neft_mapped PNM on PNM.product_sold_id = PSD.id
                      left join `product_cheques` as `PC` on (`PC`.`cheque_status` = 0 and PCM.product_cheques_id = PC.id)                          
                      left join `product_net_banking` as `PNB` on ( `PNB`.`status` = 0 and PNM.product_neft_id = PNB.id)
                      left join `product_cash` as `PCA` on ( `PCA`.`status` = 0 and PCAM.product_cash_id = PCA.id )
                      group by `client_details`.`client_id`, PCM.product_cheques_id having count( PC.cheque_status ) > 0
```

These are the table structures:

```
client_details:
client_id (PK);
client_name;

products_sold_details:
id (PK);
client_id (FK);
version;

product_cheques:
id (PK);
client_id (FK);
amount;
cheque_status;

product_net_banking:
id (PK);
client_id (FK);
amount;
status;

product_cash:
id (PK);
client_id (FK);
amount;
status;
```

products_sold_details has a many to many relation with product_cheques, product_net_banking, product_cash

client_details has many products_sold_details
client_details has many product_cheques, product_cash, product_net_banking

if there are two products for a client, and there is only one cheque for the combined product which has a status 0, then I should get count(PC.cheque_status) as 1

if there are 3 product for a client, and there are 3 cheques for that client which have status 0, then I should get the count(PC.cheque_status) as 3 for 3 cheques. 
However, what I am getting is 9 as count(PC.cheque_status) in this case.

Also, the SUM(amount) is getting multiplied with the number of products.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: try `count(distinct PC.id)` instead of `cheque_status`

Comment: Yup, that worked for count. But how about the SUM. it is getting multiplied as well.